# Bootstrap conflict with input=range in Safari

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, safari

In Safari, The thumb will be cut when it's been moving around. It seems that Bootstrap conflicts with `input` of type `range`.

It works fine in Chrome and Firefox.
Any idea about this?

```css
body {
    padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input type="range">
```

please see demo:
[input range with bootstrap](https://jsfiddle.net/bluedusk/w5817wez/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be caused by display: block.
Forcing it back to the WebKit default of display: inline-block gets rid of the clipping.

More Details See:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16809#issuecomment-122480851